# Hadoop Jobs in Multicluster

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm working on Hadoop in a multicluster way with 1 master and 2 slaves. When I lunch my program, that is compose of more jobs, I see that the jobs executes alternatively on the slaves, but i would like that the mapper tasks or the reduce tasks works concurrently on the two nodes. There's a way to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: There's a way to fix it?  what is the way ? can u elaborate

Comment: I want that the tasks of my job will work in parallalel on every node of my cluster

Comment: Programmer has no control over the number of Map tasks. Again reducers run after maps since they work on the output of the later.